# Using DataGridView to delete rows from database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Windows Form with a delete button that I'm trying to get to delete a row from the grid as well as delete it from the database.  The following code deletes from the grid, but how do I get it to delete from the database?

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in employeeGrid2.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected)
        {
            employeeGrid2.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using DataBinding? Or you are filling the DataGridView programmatically?

Comment: I am pretty sure that I am using DataBinding

Comment: Don't be pretty sure.  Are you or aren't you?  If you have set the DataSource then you are and otherwise you're not.  You should be.  Using raw ADO.NET, call Fill on a data adapter to populate a DataTable, bind it to the grid and then call Update on the same data adapter to save changes.  You do not remove items from the grid but rather call Delete on the underlying DataRowView, which you can access via the DataBoundItem property of the grid row.

Comment: Okay yes I am using DataBinding.  When I open up my form I call Fill. So would these lines help?       cs220DataSet.Tables["dbo.Employee"].Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Delete();        this.employeeTableAdapter.Update(this.cs220DataSet.Employee);